# access `headerRight` inside a screen that is hosted by stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have created a stack navigator:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const TheStack = createStackNavigator();
```

Then, This is my navigator, it claimed `component={LandingScreen}`:

```
<TheStack.Navigator ...>
  <TheStack.Screen
        name="LandingScreen"
        component={LandingScreen}
        options={{
          title: '',
          headerLeft: null,
          headerRight: () => (
            <MyHeaderRightComponent />
          ),
        }}
      />

<TheStack.Navigator>
```

As you can see above in `options` of the screen, there is `headerRight`, I have declared using `MyHeaderRightComponent` as `headerRight` so that it is shown on the right side of the header on screen.

Here is my `LandingScreen.js` :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const LandingScreen = ({navigation}) => {
   // How can I access the `headerRight` component I have set above from here? 
   ...
}
```

My question is how can I access the `headerRight` inside my *LandingScreen.js*? I know I can update or reset the `headerRight` by:

```
navigation.setOptions({headerRight:() => <NewHeaderRightComponent/>})
```

But now what I need is to access the previous already set component, not setting a new one. How to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to set headerRight at the first point on options? Why can't you use
navigation.setOptions({}) ? Assumption - you will have access to `MyHeaderRightComponent`  in LandingScreen.js

Answer (score 1):

Edits to the answer as per the request received in comments. The answer is the same. This is just further demonstration on how to use it.

```
// The screen component where you want to pass the state.

const Screen = (props) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#CCCCCC");

  const { navigation } = props //This is important or else UseEffect will be called each time any of the props change

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({ color: color }); // Where its being passed.
  }, [color, navigation]);

  return (
   <>
    <Button onPress={() => setColor("#800000")} /> // Change the color state to Maroon
    <Button onPress={() => setColor("#FED700")} /> // Change the color state to Gold
   </>
  )
}
```

Your Header Component:

```
const MyHeaderComponent = (props) {
  return(
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgColor }} />
  )
}
```

Then you can retrieve this bit in headerRight. Like this:

```
headerRight:() => <MyHeaderComponent bgColor={route.params.color} />
```

**Note:** This method is valid for [React Navigation v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/). Version 4 has a getParams() function to retrieve the params, but it was dropped in Version 5.

---

**Original Answer**

You can create a useState hook in the screen and pass its value into your header component. So, when the header component updates the state, it can be accessed from within the screen where you have defined the state.

you can use setParams() function to set the params you want to use in the header component. Then, use route.params.nameofyourprop to get them in the headerComponent, where you can consume it.

This is to pass params from outside the header to inside of it.

```
headerRight:() => <MyHeaderRightComponent propname={route.params.propvalue} />
```

This to to set the Params from outside your header which you can access inside the headerRight component.

```
const [values, setValue] = useState()

navigation.setParams({propname: value})
```

This way you can pass state between the header and the screen.

You can also pass the setValue function of the useState in this manner, but it will throw a warning because functions are objects in Javascript and thus its not possible to index them... or something on those lines.

Comment: Thanks, actually my case is the other way around, I need to update the color of `MyHeaderRightComponent` based on the state of the screen. How to do that?

Comment: The state that you pass from your screen to the header component, set them as color names or hex: 'yellow', 'red', '#000000' etc. And pass the state to the MyHeaderRightComponent. Where you can do something like this { color: state }. If you have multiple color changes to make when state changes, use if else. { color : state === 'xyz' ? 'green : 'blue' }.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm...How to pass the state from my screen to `MyHeaderRightComponent` in code? Where exactly to put the code `{color: state}` ? Could you please provide a code snippet for that part? That's actually the main thing I don't know how to do. It would be nice if you could add that in your answer.

Comment: I mean this code `headerRight:() => <MyHeaderRightComponent propname={route.params.propvalue} />` only tell how to pass the value to `MyHeaderRightComponent` from my navigator component. But how to pass the value from `LandingScreen.js` ?

Comment: @Leem.fin I've updated my answer. Try it out. Hopefully it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, one question, do you mean I have to do the destruction like this`const { navigation } = props` inside the screen component's body instead of doing it in the beginning `const Screen = ({navigation}) => {...}` ?

Comment: And what is that `route` in your code example `headerRight:() => <MyHeaderComponent bgColor={route.params.color} />
` ?

Comment: @Leem.fin you can do either. As long as it is destructured and added to the useEffect hook's array parameter, you are good. Its your call. Route is an object from React Navigation. It also requires destructuring to be used without props in `props.route.params.color`. More here -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params